# Track any kind of user interaction with an iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to reset the state of the webapp if the user has not interacted with it for a certain time.
For this I use js setTimeout that I reset on every mouse move (click, scroll) and keydown.

The problem is inside the app I have an iframe. When the user interacts with the iframe I cannot detect any interaction so the state resets.

How can I detect it?

I tried to overlay a div with pointer-events: none; but it does not fire mousemove over it.
I tried to get the focus back on the main window every time the iframe steals the focus, but it does not work.

Comment: Is the iframe from the same or a different domain?

Comment: same domain, different subdomain, but I don't have access to the app that I show in the iframe.

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible, the only way to achieve this, that I'm aware of, is using the postMessage api. But that require you adding event listeners in the content of the iframe.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I cannot do anything in the content of the iframe :(